# Menu heading to set an image but another page displayed only icons

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

My Layout page Menu Heading to set an Image...My Default Page Displayed on Correctly ,But click into another page to display a menu icon only Displayed...

MY Layout Page is as Follow:

```
       <li><a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Home")"><span><img src="Images/menu-home.png" width="30" height="11" alt="home" border="0" /></span> </a></li>

       <li><a href="@Url.Action("About", "Home")"><span><img src="Images/menu-aboutus.png" width="52" height="11" alt="about us" border="0" /></span> </a></li>

       <li><a href="@Url.Action("IAmNew", "Home")"><span><img src="Images/menu-iamnew.png" alt="iam new" border="0" /></span> </a></li>

       <li><a href="@Url.Action("CommingSoon", "Home")"><span><img src="Images/menu-comingsoon.png" width="75" height="11" alt="coming soon" border="0" /></span> </a></li>

       <li><a href="@Url.Action("FastFavourites", "Home")"><span><img src="Images/menu-past-favorites.png" width="81" height="11" alt="past favorites" border="0" /></span> </a></li>

       <li><a href="@Url.Action("SiteMap", "Home")"><span><img src="Images/menu-sitemap.png" width="44" height="11" alt="sitemap" border="0" /></span> </a></li>

       <li><a href="@Url.Action("Contact", "Home")"><span><img src="Images/menu-contactus.png" width="63" height="11" alt="contact us" border="0" /></span> </a></li>
```

Comment: clarify your question..

Comment: Thanks for your reply Duk...I solve the problem...